# Jquerypopup with json

Tags: jquery

I have a PHP action through which I process the request from AJAX and pass it as JSON. In success response, I should open the pop up which should contain `JSON` response

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/feedback/public/index/email/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        emaildata: emailid
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('div#pop-up').show();
        $(".closebtn").click(function () {
            $("div#pop-up").css('display', 'none');
        })
    }
});
```

My html div has,

```
<div id="pop-up">
    <input type="button" class="closebtn" value="close" />Firstname</br>Lastname</br>EmailId</br>Comments</br>
</div>
```

I want the data from ajax response to get append with this.I really
    dont know what todo.I am not able to use for loop also in my
    html,since I'm exit my controller in last line.Below is my
    controller.

PHP Controller

```
foreach($result AS $row)         
{ 
    $arrValues = array(
        "firstname"=>$row['firstname'], 
        "lastname"=>$row['lastname'],
        "emailid"=>$row['emailid']
    );             
}   
$this->view->data=$arrValues;  
echo json_encode(array('rows'=>$arrValues));    
exit;
```

Could you please suggest a better way for me to format the pop up
    with the JSON data in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could alter the content of the div using jQuery. Change your first line of your success-callback to something like this:

```
var html = '<input type="button" class="closebtn" value="close"/> ' 
           + data.firstname + '<br/>' + data.lastname + '<br/>' + data.emailid;
$('#pop-up').html(html).show();
```

Thus your complete success-callback would look something like this

```
success: function(data) { 
    var html = '<input type="button" class="closebtn" value="close"/> ' 
           + data.firstname + '<br/>' + data.lastname + '<br/>' + data.emailid;

    $('#pop-up').html(html).show();                       

    $(".closebtn").click(function(){ 
        $("#pop-up").hide();
    });   
}
```

Comment: Am reallly happy for this answer and lot of thanks to you.But data.firstname gives undefined in pop up.I tried with data.rows[0].firstname.Its not attempting to open the popup

Comment: If you do a `console.log(data)` in your success callback, what does the returned data look like? Do you get any JS-errors? The code is untested, so I might be missing something.

Comment: Am very sorry I'm new to Php.I dont know where the console data goes.But if try putting alert it says only 'data'.Am using array to pass values from phpcontroller to ajax.Pls help me out with this??

Comment: @Idsaru `console.log(data)` is JavaScript. If you put it in the success callback, it will write the data-object to your console. The console is available within the developer tools of your browsers. `Ctrl + Shift + J` will open the console in Chrome for instance. I need to know what the data looks like to get any further.

Comment: Hi christofer,now its working for me.I change data.firstname to data.rows[0].firstname.Then it works.Thank u co so much for your help